# Snowflake Web UI - How to Export Query Results

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-webui

I am using Snowflake's Web UI interface.

I am running the following query:

```
select top 100 *
from table_1;
```

When I click on the `COPY` button, it gives me everything into 1 giant line so it looks like this:

```
col_1     col_2    col_3   1    steve     2021-04-12 21:13:65
```

Can the Web UI output the results so the headers are on 1 row and the actual data below that instead of 1 giant line?

Comment: The `copy` button downloads each result onto a different line and also includes headers when I run it. Not sure why you were having this issue but, as you've already done anyway, probably best to use the download button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, don't use the copy button, use the actual download button right next to it.

If life has taught me anything, it's ask a question and after you've wasted a minimum of 10 minutes of someone else's time, the answer will magically appear.

Comment: welcome to the liberation of asking "something in the universe" for help, you got your help, so you are ahead. Well played.